# log format ignored for frontend 'http-in' since it has no log address

Tags: haproxy

I'm using the following [haproxy.cfg](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/rel/haproxy.cfg) from the couchdb project:

```
global
        maxconn 512
        spread-checks 5

defaults
        mode http
        log global
        monitor-uri /_haproxy_health_check
        option log-health-checks
        option httplog
        balance roundrobin
        option forwardfor
        option redispatch
        retries 4
        option http-server-close
        timeout client 150000
        timeout server 3600000
        timeout connect 500

        stats enable
        stats scope .
        stats uri /_stats

frontend http-in
         # This requires HAProxy 1.5.x
         # bind *:$HAPROXY_PORT
         bind *:5984
         default_backend couchdbs

backend couchdbs
        server couchdb1 127.0.0.1:15984 check inter 5s
        server couchdb2 127.0.0.1:25984 check inter 5s
        server couchdb3 127.0.0.1:35984 check inter 5s
```

However, I see the following in the haproxy.log file:

```
[WARNING] 244/190008 (3040) : config : log format ignored for frontend
            'http-in' since it has no log address.
```

**What does this WARNING *actually* mean?**

---

My haproxy version is:

```
# haproxy --version
HA-Proxy version 1.5.8 2014/10/31
```

Answer (score 10):

It is upset because the config file says to use the "log specified in [global]" (which is the `log global` statement), but the `global` section does not contain any log specifications.

To fix this problem, put `log 127.0.0.1 local0` (or your favorite syslog server and facility), as described [here](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#log%20%28Process%20management%20and%20security%29)